# Fine-tune Bert for specific domain (unsupervised)

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, bert-language-model

I want to fine-tune BERT on texts that are related to a specific domain (in my case related to engineering). The training should be unsupervised since I don't have any labels or anything. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you get the solution to it? I find the huggingface's script very long and struggle to get an in-depth explanation. Do share if you have got your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you in fact want to is continue pre-training BERT on text from your specific domain. What you do in this case is to continue training the model as masked language model, but on your domain-specific data.

You can use the [`run_mlm.py`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_mlm.py) script from the Huggingface's Transformers.

Comment: do I also have to extend the vocabulary in when continuing the pre-training? I am asking, because the text I want to train Bert on has very specific terms related to power plants.

Comment: You can. There are a lot of slots in the best vocab file where you can put in your domain-specific words.