# Is it possible to further fine tune a BERT model on additional data for huggingface library

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I have already fine tuned a BERT model on a dataset im using. But as I review the results I want to add additional data to the training. I do not want to retrain the whole model though as it takes a long time since im not running on GPU. Is it possible to just feed the new dataset and on top of the fine tuned model? I'm using huggingface library for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fine-tune Bert for specific domain (unsupervised)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712375/fine-tune-bert-for-specific-domain-unsupervised)

Comment: No I'm not sure if it's the same but I already did the fine tuning for a specific domain and save this model. But now my problem is after fine tuning I have created more dataset for the model to train with. So at first i had 800 rows for the model to fine tune with. Now I have additional 300 rows. I do not want to combine both to make 1,100 rows and fine tune the model completely from the pretrained one. Instead I want to use the saved model from the 800 rows and fine tune further with the additional 300 rows. Is this possible? and is it doing the same thing as you commented?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like re-training or incremental training.
You can try out the `creme` library for the same:
https://github.com/MaxHalford/creme