# How to use run_mlm with unlabeled text

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I want to fine-tune a pre-trained huggingface model for a particular domain. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712375/fine-tune-bert-for-specific-domain-unsupervised) answer I know I can do it using [run_mlm.py](http://run_mlm.py) but I can't understan which format should I use for my text file. I tried to use a simple structure with one document per line and I get the following error:

```
python run_mlm.py --model_name_or_path "neuralmind/bert-base-portuguese-cased" --train_file ../data/full_corpus.csv  --output models/  --do_train


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_mlm.py", line 449, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_mlm.py", line 384, in main
    load_from_cache_file=not data_args.overwrite_cache,
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/dataset_dict.py", line 303, in map
    for k, dataset in self.items()
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/dataset_dict.py", line 303, in <dictcomp>
    for k, dataset in self.items()
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 1260, in map
    update_data=update_data,
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 157, in wrapper
    out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py", line 163, in wrapper
    out = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 1529, in _map_single
    writer.write_batch(batch)
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/arrow_writer.py", line 278, in write_batch
    pa_table = pa.Table.from_pydict(typed_sequence_examples)
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 1474, in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_pydict
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 322, in pyarrow.lib.asarray
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 222, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 110, in pyarrow.lib._handle_arrow_array_protocol
  File "/mnt/sdb/data-mwon/paperChega/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/arrow_writer.py", line 100, in __arrow_array__
    if trying_type and out[0].as_py() != self.data[0]:
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 1058, in pyarrow.lib.Array.__getitem__
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 540, in pyarrow.lib._normalize_index
IndexError: index out of bounds
```